# Queue Import error after running exe

Tags: python, python-2.7

i created exe using py2exe after that i facing this below error
i checked in lib directory and Queue.py is already present in that directory
please help me to resolve this issue
im using python 2.7

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Game2048.py", line 12, in <module>
  File "pynput\__init__.pyc", line 23, in <module>
  File "pynput\keyboard\__init__.pyc", line 44, in <module>
  File "pynput\keyboard\_win32.pyc", line 32, in <module>
  File "pynput\_util\__init__.pyc", line 34, in <module>
  File "six.pyc", line 203, in load_module
  File "six.pyc", line 115, in _resolve
  File "six.pyc", line 82, in _import_module
ImportError: No module named Queue
```

Comment: Is "Queue.pyc" or "Queue.pyo" available in the "library.zip"-file created by py2exe? If necessary modify the setup.py so that py2exe creates it instead of bundling everything into the exe-file.

Comment: After adding the "Queue.pyc" in "library.zip" my exe is working fine.
But any idea why "Queue" is missing in library?

Comment: This needed a longer answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

py2exe decides which modules to include in the final ZIP-file or executable by examining the `import` statements in those module(s) explicitly mentioned in setup.py. It then adds these imported modules to the dependencies of the executable and checks all import statements in these newly added modules to find further necessary modules and so on until no more new modules can be found in the imports.

Here, the module `Queue` is imported in a dynamical way, basically by calling something like `__import__("Queue")` which can't be automatically recognized by py2exe. Therefore the module isn't seen as necessary.

To solve this add an artificial dependency in a module which is already added to the executable:

```
if False:
    import Queue
```

The code has no effect but py2exe sees the `import` statement and will follow it.